# Twilio Whatsapp pass sandbox to production

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I developed a chatbot in sandbox, i did a lot of tests and now it time to enable production. I bought Twilio US phone number with Voice, Fax, SMS, MMS capabilities. Then, 2 days ago i was completed [This form](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp/request-access?twaccsid=AC66e1cc8d7e0f36cf76f1710d32e851bf) request for Whatsapp, with the phone number mentioned and my Facebook Business acount and other requirements. First, I pretend use this chatbot from Uruguay. Then, maybe other regional countries.

Here my questions:

I did the correct procedure for production? or I need an phone number locally for the request? How many days aprox. i'll have a response and continue my put in production?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It sounds like you did the correct procedure for production. That application is taken onto Facebook/WhatsApp and when they approve your account you will be provided a WhatsApp number that you can then use with your chatbot.

I'm afraid I don't know how long the approval process will take as it is in the hands of WhatsApp.